# Включение jumbo-фреймов на сети

Tags: сеть, ethernet, d-link

Предоставляем клиенту на сети L2 канал, появилась необходимость включить ему поддержку jumbo кадров, т.к. в стандартный mtu не пролезает. Никогда с этим не работал, кто-нибудь знает как настраивается этот функционал на оборудовании dlink и нет ли риска потери связи с оборудованием?

Comment: Если не секрет, зачем это? И могу тут вроде не при чем, если я правильно помню, фреймы на уровень выше в реализации.

Comment: Я же написал, возникла необходимость включить клиенту. Т.к. mtu отправляемых им пакетов выше стандартного, снижать не может/не хочет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Железо должно поддерживать, с обоих сторон, специальных настроек как правило не требуется, только опция включения/отключения режима. По логике если завести сетевую карту например с помощью PPPOE на jumbo режим, то все остальное оборудование переключиться автоматически, если эта поддержка присутствует в железе. Если нет, ничего не получиться.

В `Dlink` L2 комутаторах поддержка `jumbo frames` включается коммандой с консоли: `enable jumbo_frame`, посмотреть: `show jumbo_frame`, но, присутствует не во всех линейках оборудования.

И надо помнить что jumbo-фреймы применимы только к гигабитным проводным соединениям. Они не используются на 100Мб проводных соединениях или любом беспроводном соединении. Очевидно, что для того, чтобы jumbo frames работали в сети, все устройства на пути должны поддерживать их.